# I asked this question in Politics, is it acceptable to ask it here?

Tags: discussion

This question seems to be directly related to Kant morality. Is there anything I need to change in the question to ask it in Philosophy?

https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/14091/in-the-syrian-conflict-was-there-a-higher-moral-principle-that-stopped-the-us-f?noredirect=1#comment49201_14091

Comment: The question why the US didn't do something is not really on topic here. The question what [Kant] would say about this would be.

Comment: "Can there be a categorical imperative for war?" might be one approach at specifying this in theoretical terms

Comment: Keelan, thank you, that helps, askin a general question about Kant's morality as it applies to international intervention.