# How does Kant's view apply to military intervention in the affairs of another state?

Tags: discussion

Need to frame this question, proceeding from the meta question [here](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3310/i-asked-this-question-in-politics-is-it-acceptable-to-ask-it-here?noredirect=1#comment4589_3310).

Is this question ready for asking on the Real Philosophy stackex (not meta?)

> I have briefly read through and viewed some material on Kant's theory
>   of morality. How would the moral system put forward by Kant apply to the morality of military
>   intervention in a civil war of another state be viewed by Kant's
>   morality? How would this view be formulated for all sides involved in
>   such a conflict? For example in the [US Army "involvement" in the Russian Civil War.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Expeditionary_Force_Siberia)

Comment: I would think so.  You can see Kant's notions of politics in his own writings on 'Perpetual Peace'.  One of the principles is that "No State Shall by Force Interfere with the Constitution or Government of Another State"  I would assume from that notion that we are to allow civil wars to be worked through among those who will have to live in the resulting state.  Otherwise we are setting up a disagreement within the state about a moral debt to us, which is grounds for a latter, different kind of civil strife.

Comment: "jobermark" thanks for the brief but succint comment. It almost answers the question but I will consider asking it anyway on the Real Phiosophy Stackex